# SOAP request works with SoapUI but not with Savon, how to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, soap, ruby-on-rails-5, savon

I tested a SOAP API in SoapUI and it worked just fine.

I then implemented the same request in my Rails 5 app using Savon. It worked for a few weeks and then stopped working. SoapUI still works so the API provider of course tells me that the error is in my app.

The error I get is very generic:

```
404 not found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

1. It worked in my app
2. Now it does not work anymore in my app
3. In SoapUI the request works

I tried adding `log_level: :debug` to my client but do not get any more details.

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'URL')
response = client.call(:action, message: {})
```

Any ideas on how to start debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a Ruby script *outside* of RoR then more people might be able to help. I for myself have no idea how Rails works but I certainly know a bit of Ruby :-).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I don't know if that's a Savon Bug, but Savon extracted a wrong Endpoint URL from the WSDL, whereas SoapUI extracted the correct Endpoint URL.

Now I am overwriting the URL with the correct one:

```
client.wsdl.endpoint = URI.parse ENDPOINT_URL
```

and it works again.

Comment: I never use the WSDL. I always create a client without it.